# How to properly declare variables in the function call - Codeigniter

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and in my controller I have

```
function index($var_22) {
 // BLABLA
}
```

So if I dont pass the $var_22 variable I will get an error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Claims::index()
```

But I dont need to pass it all of the time, what should I use when I do not pass that variable in order not to get the error. (I dont want to turn off global error reporting)

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a default value for it and then check into the controller code if the parameter is default or not. Something like this:

```
function index($var_22 = FALSE)
{
   if (!$var_22) {
       // code for the initialized parameter
   } else {
      // code with no parameter
   }    
}
```

or

```
function index($var_22 = "")
    {
       if (!empty($var_22)) {
           // code for the initialized parameter
       } else {
          // code with no parameter
       }    
    }
```